# (Django) Split frontend and backend

Tags: django, brunch

I want to split front ([Brunch](http://brunch.io/)) and back ([Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)). I have this folder structure:

```
backend
  mydjangoapp
  static
    mydjangoapp
      image
      javascripts
      stylesheets
      index.html

frontend
  app
  public
    image
    javascripts
    stylesheets
    index.html
```

So for example, path to stylesheet inside **index.html** would be:

- **[Backend]** `static/mydjangoapp/stylesheets/app.css`
- **[Frontend]** `/stylesheets/app.css`

I use **frontend paths** to test frontend locally with brunch server and **backend paths** with django app on deploy. Currently deploy procedure looks like this:

1. brunch build
2. move content of **public** folder to `backend/static/mydjangoapp`
3. change all paths inside **index.html**, **app.js** etc. to match backend
   static path.

Not very convenient. Is there a way to do it automatically? I guess i could change static paths in backend to match frontend or write a script to do it. But its not really a proper solution, is it? There must be a way to render **index.html** directly from **frontend** folder and load static files without changing paths. Tried to google it, but no luck.

Comment: Have you considered fabric? It allows you to build little deployment scripts that automate this process. I think it could handle steps 1 and 2; for 3, consider including an if statement that checks if DEBUG is on

Comment: Thanks @ubadub, but i think it would be easier to just write a script. Not exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Do you run the frontend app *without* django (locally or otherwise)? As well as what kind of paths do you have in js and so on? For HTML, you could easily use something like `static-jade-brunch` and put '{{prefix}}stylesheets/app.css` in your HTML, then configure `static-jade-brunch` to use either `/` or `static/mydjangoapp/` depending on an ENV variable or whatever.

Also, you can configure Brunch to put the compiled files directly into `../backend/static/mydjangoapp` — https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#paths

Comment: Oh, i forgot to mention that i test frontend locally on brunch server, sorry (edited the original post). Lot of useful info though. Thanks, @Gosha Arinich! I think its kinda solves my problem. Also maybe i should consider [nginx](http://nginx.org/) in front of my django app to resolve static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. I've done some research and came to this solution:

1) I used [nginx](http://nginx.org/) server in front of my django application and configured it to resolve static files like so (nginx config file, http section):

```
server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    server_name _;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    location ~* .*\/.+\..+$ {
        root path/to/my/static/files;
    }
}
```

So static paths are the same as in **frontend**. No need to change those. Django app don't resolve static files at all. It just loads a template.

2) I wrote a python script to compile and copy needed files to **backend** (it sits in **frontend** root directory):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import call
import shutil
import os

BACKEND_FOLDER = "../backend/ui/public"

call(["brunch", "build", "-p"])
shutil.rmtree(BACKEND_FOLDER)
shutil.copytree("public", BACKEND_FOLDER)

print ("Deployed to: " + BACKEND_FOLDER)
```

Now all that i need to do is to run that script.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use either `post-brunch` or `after-brunch` plugins to copy the files from `frontend/public` to the django static directory of your choice.

Example with [after-brunch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/after-brunch)

    `exports.config = {
      plugins: {
        afterBrunch: [
          'cp -r public ../backend/static'
          // cp -r /from/frontend/path /to/backend/path
        ]
      }
    }`

Example with [post-brunch](https://github.com/marcinbunsch/post-brunch)

    `exports.config = {
      plugins: {
        postBrunch: function(files) {
          console.log("Run custom javascript code to copy files.")
        }
      }
    }`